# BIOS posting irregularly after Windows Update

Tags: bios

Alright, so here's the deal. I moved my PC into my new place and hooked it all up. I used the system fine for 2 days and then I did a refresh of the PC from the Windows settings (essentially giving me a clean install feel). After doing this, I formatted two of my SSDs and also a partition of a drive that I'd hooked up with the Optane M.2 (without unhooking it). After all this, when I shut the system down and ran it the next day, the BIOS wasn't posting. Funnily enough, when I shut down the system and turned the PSU switch off and then on, and  then proceeded to turn the PC on it worked fine and booted up with everything working just as it is supposed to. So, at this point the only solution is to toggle the PSU switch and then proceed to turn on the system. I know this is a lengthy one, but any ideas what might be causing this finnicky boot problem? 
P.S I felt statically discharging the mobo by basically holding down the power button gave the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Lets step through this logically:

1. The machine was working fine
2. You physically moved the machine
3. You did a Windows reset
4. The BIOS is no longer posting

So what has changed?  You moved the machine and did a Windows reset.

What do we know?  A Windows reset is not the problem.  Why?  The BIOS will post before any operating system loads.  A BIOS will post even if there is no operating system.

What does that leave?  The fact you moved the computer.  I *highly* suspect something has come loose while moving the computer.  Moving a computer can cause the case, and therefore the motherboard, to flex.  This flexing can cause memory to come loose, the CPU to not be socketed correctly, expansion cards to become unseated, etc.  I would open up the computer and remove each component and then properly reinsert them, taking care that they are properly installed.  Components have lots of little connections and if that device is inserted at the slightest angle, it can cause two connections to overlap and short.  Also, while you are in there, it couldnt hurt the clean out any dust with some canned air.

Comment: Hey Keltari that's what I was gonna do..... The method of elimination! Will keep ya posted.... Gonna do it tomorrow! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be try resetting the CMOS. Carefully remove the mobos battery and use the Jumper switch. *Remember YOU MUST REMOVE THE POWER FIRST*!!!. If the mobo doesn't have cmos jumper then use a flat headed screw driver and touch both contacts of the battery socket.

Hold for 20 seconds to remove residual power then re-install the battery and try booting to the BIOS DEL or F2 and then load optimized defaults and save. Reboot and then you can enter bios again and do XMP profiles or whatever.

Comment: How is this a "best bet?"  Why would resetting CMOS help?  How does this explain the behavior?

Answer (score -2):

1) Reset BIOS to defaults

2) Check for BIOS updates